# How to float an image in an HTML email

Tags: html, email

I have the following HTML that I am both sending in an email and using to create a web page.

```
<div>
   <a name="id-23"></a>
   <h2>Free Legal Defense Services for Lester et al</h2>
   <div class="ExternalClass43FFE3E27D8B457FBF45BD9E20AC7FE3">
      <p><img src="http://www.mynevadacounty.com/NC/CEO/Resources/FridayMemo/FM-20121026-State Capitol.jpg" alt="" style="margin:5px;float:left;vertical-align:auto" />
         Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
   </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

The webpage wraps the text as I would like, but the email does not:

[image]

How can I get the text to properly wrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [**wonderful article about HTML Email**](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails)...

**99% of your CSS wont work**

So, you're stuck using tables if you want to get really down and dirty with a custom html email.  Mail Chimp has a bunch of free html email templates that i'd recommend starting out with as a base... tables are a pain in the freaking ass.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that what works varies very much from email-application to email-application. What works in Outlook, might not work in the Gmail-webclient, OSX Mail-application or Thunderbird, or the other way around. HTML-emails are a pain indeed!

Comment: yuuup! that article does a great detail discouraging you towards custom email implementations... do yourself a favor and use some templates, seriously... DO NOT INVENT THIS.

Answer (score 3):

Placing the image in a separate table cell as your content simply creates columns - it doesn't wrap your text around the image. Using the obsolete attribute **align="left"**, you can get your email to behave similarly as the site where the image floats to the left and the text wraps around it.

However, your margin property is also ignored by Outlook and your text will butt up against the image. To remedy that, use the obsolete attributes **hspace="5"** (adds 5px of spacing to the left and right) and **vspace="5"** (adds 5px of spacing to the top and bottom).

Unfortunately, there is no way to target just the right and bottom using these attributes, so you'll end up with spacing all around the image. If you're not okay with that and *need* spacing on *only* the right and bottom, then I'd suggest adding that white space to the image itself. Otherwise, read on for the more complicated approach.

If you use hspace and vspace, or adding white space to the image, then I'd suggest to leave out the margin property (or set it to 0) from the in-line style attribute to avoid double spacing in the email clients that *don't* ignore it.

```
<div>
   <a name="id-23"></a>
   <h2>Free Legal Defense Services for Lester et al</h2>
   <div class="ExternalClass43FFE3E27D8B457FBF45BD9E20AC7FE3">
      <p><img src="http://www.mynevadacounty.com/NC/CEO/Resources/FridayMemo/FM-20121026-State Capitol.jpg" alt="" align="left" hspace="5" vspace="5" style="float:left;" />
         Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
   </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

**The more complicated approach:**

Because the obsolete attribute "align" works on both images and tables, we're going to put your single image into a table and float *that* instead. Then, apply the padding to the single table cell element holding your image.

```
<div>
   <a name="id-23"></a>
   <h2>Free Legal Defense Services for Lester et al</h2>
   <div class="ExternalClass43FFE3E27D8B457FBF45BD9E20AC7FE3">
      <!--[if mso]>
      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="130" height="60">
         <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0 5px 5px 0;">
            <![endif]-->
               <img align="left" width="125" height="53" style="float: left; width: 125px; height: 53px; margin: 0 5px 5px 0;" src="http://www.mynevadacounty.com/NC/CEO/Resources/FridayMemo/FM-20121026-State Capitol.jpg" alt="" />
            <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <![endif]-->
      <p>
         Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
   </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

Sources:

- [Floating Images and Tables in Outlook](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1543-responsive-allowing-text-to-flow-around-images#comment-4930)
- [Margins and Padding around Images in Outlook](https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/email/why-are-margins-and-padding-around-my-image-not-rendering-in-outlook#method-1-use-hspace-or-vspace)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a table row width 2 of tds!

instead of "float:right" try this

```
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td >
                               your text Here                  
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <img src="###" alt="" border="0" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```